# How can I save a file url submitted in a form with curl?

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, curl

I am trying to create an upload plugin that allows for a user to upload any file from their computer or from a url they type into the provided text field.

This is the script I have to upload files from a local disk:

```
session_start();
//Loop through each file
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['file']); $i++) {
  //Get the temp file path
  if (isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i]))
  {
  $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
  }

  //Make sure we have a filepath
  if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
    //Setup our new file path
    if (isset($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]))
    $newFilePath = "./uploaded_files/" . $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
    }

    //Upload the file into the temp dir
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {

    echo "Uploaded Successfully!<br />";

}
```

All I need now is for the curl part to take the file from the url submitted in the text field and save it to the same location.

Here is the cURL I have so far:

```
function GetImageFromUrl($link) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$link);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

$sourcecode=GetImageFromUrl("http://domain.com/path/image.jpg");
$savefile = fopen('/home/path/image.jpg', 'w');
fwrite($savefile, $sourcecode);
fclose($savefile);
```

Comment: So what is the problem exactly?

Comment: @GoogleGuy I want to have a text input box on the front end where users submit a url. Said url then goes through the curl. I can't my code to do that. What can I add to the curl to tell it to look for a submitted text field?

Comment: Why did you deleted and re  post this question when it was clearly identified as duplicate  ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a specific reason you want to use curl? Here's how you can simply do that without it:

```
$url = $_POST['url'];
$file_content = file_get_contents($url);
$file_name = array_pop(explode('/', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH)));
file_put_contents('/home/path/' . $file_name, $file_content);
```

You should also consider looking into $url and checking if it's valid before working with it.

Comment: with `if (isset($_POST['url']))`?

Comment: My guess is you are working with images, so checking for proper image format and size would be a good start.

Comment: I will ultimately be accepting all filetypes, but for now while I deal with syntax and making everything work...yes, images.